# Simple Excel IF statement not working.

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have no idea why this isn't working. It looks exactly like multiple sources I have found around the web. What am I missing?

Code:

```
=IF(A1="Select all",B1="Yep",B1="Nope")
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: You gotta post the whole sheet

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. This is all there is on the sheet. I'm just testing formulas for more complicated stuff later and have already hit a snag on something that looks like it should be super simple. I probably should have used something other than "Select all" I suppose haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to put the result values in the 2nd and 3rd arguments:

```
=IF(A1="Select all","Yep","Nope")
```

It looked like you were trying to assign the values to B1 cell, but what actually happens is you get the result of doing a comparison to check whether B1 is equal to "Yep", which is causes a circular reference error because the formula tries to look at itself.

Comment: OMG. I didn't see the forest for the trees! Thanks so much. I'm gonna go over here and feel a little foolish for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to say B1="Yep"  Just put

```
=IF(A1="Select all", "Yep", "Nope")
```